# TypeError: 'connect' only accepts a callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb

when I try `node index.js` my error comes with `TypeError: 'connect' only accepts a callback`, then I'm confused about how to solve this problem.
The error goes to mongo_client.js:165:11

I did a tutorial about how to connect to mongodb with Nodejs but, I found a problem that ppl never had since now

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient();
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27107/testedmtdev';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client){
    if(err){
        console.log('Unable to connect to the Mongodb server. Error : ', err);
    } else {
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
            console.log('Connected to mongodb, webservice running on port 3000');
        })
    }
});
```

I expect the output of 'Connected to mongodb, webservice running on port 3000'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because you're actually calling `MongoClient` with *no* parameters.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient();  // <-- your calling the method here
```

Make a change to just use a reference

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;  // <-- do *not* call method
```

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect